# Same email for all comments

Tags: comments, author, email, subscription

I have **An administrator must always approve the comment** checked, as well as *Email me whenever* **Anyone posts a comment**.

This sends an email to the post author. I don't want that. I have one person in charge of comments on my site, and I want that one person to be receiving all those emails.

Any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Just change to `to` address for these emails.

Sample code, not tested:

```
// hook in late, to avoid side effects.
add_filter( 'comment_notification_headers', 'wpse_73855__change_comment_notify_to' );

function wpse_73855__change_comment_notify_to( $input )
{
    if ( 'comment_notification_headers' === current_filter() )
    {
        add_filter( 'wp_mail', __FUNCTION__ );
        return $input;
    }

    $input['to'] = get_option( 'admin_email' );
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return $input;
}
```